# How to Test my algorithm that solves "Flowers" Interview Street challenge

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm solving the challenge "Flowers" at InterviewStreet:

> You and your K-1 friends want to buy N flowers. Flower number i has
>   host ci. Unfortunately the seller does not like a customer to buy a
>   lot of flowers, so he tries to change the price of flowers for
>   customer who had bought flowers before. More precisely if a customer
>   has already bought x flowers, he should pay (x+1)*ci dollars to buy
>   flower number i.
>
> You and your K-1 firends want to buy all N flowers in such a way that
>   you spend the as few money as possible.

but my solution is failing the test cases: 3, 5 and 7
so I'm getting a score of 7/10.

I already tested thoroughly my code, and it's giving me the right anwers all the time, so I can't see why I'm not getting full score for this challenge.

Basically what I do is that, if there are more or equal friends than flowers to buy, I will return the sum of the price of the flowers.

If there are more flowers to buy than friends, then I would sort the price of the flowers in descendent order (more expensive to cheaper), and make the friends buy one at a time.

```
typedef unsigned long long int uint64;
uiRemainder = n % k;

    sort(viFlowersCost.begin(), viFlowersCost.end(), greater<int>()); //Sorted Array Descending

    if(uiRemainder == 0) {
            for(a = 0; a < n; a+=k) {
                    for(b = 0; b < k; ++b) {
                            ui64Result += (x+1)*viFlowersCost[a+b];
                    }
            ++x;
            }
    } else {
            for(a = 0; a < (n/k)*k; a+=k) {
                    for(b = 0; b < k; ++b) {
                            ui64Result += (x+1)*viFlowersCost[a+b];
                    }   
                    ++x;
            }   
            for(b = 0; b <= uiRemainder; ++b) {
                    ui64Result += (x+1)*viFlowersCost[a+b];
            }   
    }   

    cout<<ui64Result;
```

My question is: What inputs would make my program to throw an incorrect answer given the following constraints:

Constraint :

> 1 <= N, K  <= 100
>
> Each flower costs not more than 1,000,000

I already tested for extreme cases:

N = 99 K = 100 and a 100 flowers follow with prices in the range of 900,000 - 1,000,000
it is still giving me the right answer.

For example the following test case:

> 99 100
>
> 916807 972425 933847 933809 997490 906570 926534 936300 963336 917637
>   956205 927011 966648 942300 906839 911128 967915 931564 970607 941177
>   935338 918421 905061 977177 911389 959618 991125 966236 942883 980278
>   979549 991459 907876 928248 908003 970585 967394 962906 915297 950976
>   906662 989573 985875 903158 911494 990185 911664 975093 934338 976986
>   918541 910894 911602 952041 907953 967915 977677 982920 990006 959603
>   908295 943832 917462 911173 976614 996246 935262 945460 987876 973350
>   949546 930732 922685 988390 912489 979841 918856 953461 923072 985130
>   906338 917402 975289 931717 927872 920676 914295 994827 997989 975217
>   977181 914545 991968 935860 994059 913399 927867 912266 948655 944224

My program outputs:

> 93697342

Which is the right answer according to interview street

Comment: Where is the sort you talked about?

Comment: it's just one line above that, `std::sort`
viFlowersCost is just `std::vector<int>`

Comment: I just tried an input over the constraints. 1000 Flowers ranging from 1,000,000 - 10,000,000 
It's still throwing the right answer.

Comment: Why do you need to do an if depending on the uiRemainder? That looks kind of fishy.

Comment: uiRemainder allows me to break the problem into groups, if n is a multiple of K, then it would be n/k groups. Otherwise, then it would be (n/k)*k + mod(n/k) groups that I need to iterate over and over... it's kind of hard to explain it in words, visually is easier to understand.

Comment: can you give me link of your questions ?